# meaning of the phrase

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

Can this phrase be used this way?: to mock at someone who said some kind of nonsense or the way what he did or the way how he looks. Or is it possible?

For example: I can't with/from you**r** stupid laugh.

> I can't with/from you

[urbandictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%20can%27t%20with%20you)

Urbandictionary's Definition:

Meaning, you're a weirdo. You need help

Example: I can't with you right now Joe

Comment: You could improve this question by copying that relevant parts of the Urban Dictionary definition, so that we could see what you're thinking without leaving this website.

Comment: Note that a) the UrbanDictionary can have anything added by anyone and is thus not very reliable and b) that entry has 18 up-votes and 37 down-votes. I've never heard this phrase and it just sounds like nonsense. I would try to understand it as "I can't deal with you", which is more or less what it purports to mean. I don't see any version with 'from' rather than 'with' making sense.

Comment: @simonatrcl are there any phrases that fit my context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is extremely informal and slang! It's also extremely recent new use.

It likely derives from the phrase "I just can't", meaning "I am very frustrated and just can't continue to engage with [this specific thing]".

Hence, "I just can't with you", meaning "You are very frustrating to me (ongoing) and I just can't continue to engage with you."

(The speaker is probably a young person who uses social media / computer network communication)